# How can I change/define the terminal size for a build CLI Node.js Tool with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, figlet

I have built a small tool. This also works. I had made a banner with figlet for fun. On my normal screen it looks good. But when I try the tool on my 13 inch laptop the banner is shifted and you can't read it. I can now make it manually larger... Can I also define a fixed size for the terminal? So that the terminal always has the same size no matter where I start the tool?

```
clear();

console.log(
    chalk.green(
        figlet.textSync('SYSTEMINFO', {
            horizontalLayout: 'full',
            font: 'ANSI Shadow',
        }),
    ),
);
```

Comment: You cannot. The terminal depends on physical screen/window size, not on what your CLI application needs. This basically means your CLI application needs to scale based on the screen/window size, not the other way around.

Comment: @ Sergiu Paraschiv Ok. Thanks for the quick reply.